# Counting the number of layers in a neural network

Tags: neural-network

I am going over the Udacity tutorial on Neural Networks.

Here's a diagram from the tutorial:

[image]

What makes this a '2 layer neural network'?

- I was [under the impression](http://ufldl.stanford.edu/tutorial/supervised/MultiLayerNeuralNetworks/) that the first layer, the actual input, should be considered a layer and included in the count.
- This screenshot shows 2 matrix multiplies and 1 layer of ReLu's. To me this looks like 3 layers. **There are arrows pointing from one to another, indicating they are separate.** Include the input layer, and this looks like a 4 layer NN.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Input layer is a layer, it's not wrong to say that.

However, when calculating the depth of a deep neural network, we only consider the layers that have tunable weights.

Comment: So in the picture above that I posted, I see 2 matrix multiplies and a ReLu. Isn't that 3 layers?

Comment: ReLU is just element-wise activation, not a weighted layer.

Comment: @MonicaHeddneck nn0p is correct. Don't be too concern what's exactly drawn in the picture. Focus on the actual layer architecture (the text below).

Comment: ohhhhh so ReLu's can be layers because they are not parametric! This is exactly what I was wondering about.

Comment: @MonicaHeddneck ???? ReLu is activation, nothing to do with parametric.

Comment: @StudentT, yes, and this is why you don't count the ReLus as an official 'layer', right?

Comment: @MonicaHeddneck ReLus is part of the hidden layer. The picture you show is misleading.

Answer (score 9):

This is a 2-layer network because it has a single hidden layer and an output layer. We don't count the first layer. When we say 3 layers, we actually mean 2 hidden layers and an output layer. Perhaps this helps you?

**EDIT:** We don't count the input layer because there's no parameter (bias + weights). In actual implementation, it's not implemented. Netural network framework simply "connects" the input features to the first adjustable layer (eg: hidden layer).

[image]

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. Can you take a look at the image I posted -- I think I'm seeing 3 layers that all are parameterized.

Comment: @MonicaHeddneck I don't know what exactly the picture is drawing, but it's not important. The text below tells you exactly why it's a two-layer network.

Comment: I agree now...the text is correct and the picture is misleading. When I asked this question, I wasn't sure if the picture was correct and the text was misleading. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @SmallChess Hi, can you please give the URL of the article/webpage from which you imported the picture containing the two NN diagrams and the `Naming convertions:` paragraph ?

Comment: @SebMa I googled partial of the text, luckily google is smart enough :)
http://cs231n.github.io/neural-networks-1/